# AS3 AIR - How to handle Push Notifications for Deep Linking?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, push-notification, deep-linking

I am using Urban Airship for Push Notifications. It is working fine.

Currently, the moment I click on these notifications, it launches my app.

However, now I would like to handle these Push Notifications to ensure that the relevant screen in my app is shown up when I click on the notifications (deep linking). Can anyone here point me as to how I should go about this for iOS and Android?

At the push notification level, I will need to send in some additional parameters in my notification so that I can pass the same to my app and thereby the relevant screen can be loaded up. How to pass these parameters to my app?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onInvoke listener anf retrieve the information coming from the notification. The extension should support this feature of course. Read here for more info about the OnInvoke http://myappsnippet.com/gcm